# onchange like function in vb.net similar to the jquery

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

I want to execute a query when a user chooses from a dropdown box, I know it can be done in jquery with the onchange function but I am not sure how to perform it using vb.net

Any ideas on how to do it? or is this even possible in vb.net?

I am using microsoft visual basic 2008 express edition.

Comment: ASP.net webforms right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET, you can use `onselectedindexchanged` event, similar to the `SelectedIndexChanged` of winforms:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
     onselectedindexchanged="myFunction">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In your code behind:

```
Protected Sub ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddl1.SelectedIndexChanged
     'Your logic here
End Sub
```

**Update**:

In winforms, you can use `SelectedIndexChanged`, but I suggest `SelectionChangeCommitted` event in order to fire the event if the user is really the one who changed the selections.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    'Your code goes here...
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry i meant for vb.net i just used jquery as an example :)

Comment: thank you will try it now :) what if i want to pass the selected choice to a query statement? what should i do then?

Comment: Use `SelectedItem` property to get or set the selected choice in the combobox. Example for above: `ComboBox1.SelectedItem`

Comment: how can i execute my query using this function? can you show an example thank you :)